# data.table average by group provide different results when using mean() and sum()/.N

Tags: r, data.table

When calculating the average by group in a data.table I get distinct results:

```
qty <- c(1:6)
name <- c("a", "b","a", "a", "c","b" )
type <- c("i", "i", "i", "f", "f", "f")

DT <- data.table(qty,name,type) 

DT[, avg_mean  := mean(qty)   , by = .(name, type)]
DT[, avg_sum_N := sum(qty)/.N , by = .(name, type)]

 > DT
     qty   name   type avg_mean avg_sum_N
   <int> <char> <char>    <num>     <num>
1:     1      a      i        2         2
2:     2      b      i        4         2
3:     3      a      i        2         2
4:     4      a      f        2         4
5:     5      c      f        6         5
6:     6      b      f        5         6
```

I would expect that `avg_mean` and `avg_sum_N` would be exactly the same, such as `avg_sum_N`.
Why are they different? Thank you.

Please find below session info.

```
> packageVersion('data.table')
[1] ‘1.14.3’
> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 19044)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252  LC_CTYPE=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    LC_MONETARY=Portuguese_Brazil.1252
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                       LC_TIME=Portuguese_Brazil.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] zoo_1.8-10        lubridate_1.8.0   RPostgres_1.4.3   DBI_1.1.2         stringi_1.7.6     readxl_1.4.0     
 [7] gsubfn_0.7        proto_1.0.0       stringr_1.4.0     magrittr_2.0.3    stringdist_0.9.8  fuzzyjoin_0.1.6  
[13] data.table_1.14.3

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] Rcpp_1.0.8.3     pillar_1.7.0     compiler_4.1.0   cellranger_1.1.0 tools_4.1.0      bit_4.0.4       
 [7] lattice_0.20-44  lifecycle_1.0.1  tibble_3.1.6     pkgconfig_2.0.3  rlang_1.0.2      cli_3.2.0       
[13] rstudioapi_0.13  writexl_1.4.0    parallel_4.1.0   dplyr_1.0.8      hms_1.1.1        generics_0.1.2  
[19] vctrs_0.4.1      grid_4.1.0       bit64_4.0.5      tidyselect_1.1.2 glue_1.6.2       R6_2.5.1        
[25] fansi_1.0.3      tcltk_4.1.0      blob_1.2.3       purrr_0.3.4      ellipsis_0.3.2   assertthat_0.2.1
[31] utf8_1.2.2       crayon_1.5.1
```

Comment: I don't see that, for me both `avg_` columns are the same.

Comment: Can you show the `packageVersion('data.table')`

Comment: I am guessing that this is related to GForce optimization which uses `gsum` and `gmean` internally.  Try setting it off with `options(datatable.optimize=1)` and then use your code.  Then, it would use `sum` and `mean` from `base R`

Comment: Or otherwise use `DT[, avg_mean  := base::mean(qty)   , by = .(name, type)]` and `DT[, avg_sum_N := base::sum(qty)/.N , by = .(name, type)]`

Comment: Using `options(datatable.optimize=1)` solved the problem

Comment: But I would expect that the code would work regardless options settings, it is a inconsistent behavior.

Comment: @FabioCorrea I agree.  It could be a bug or undesired behavior.  Assuming this is a dev version, they may get it corrected in the CRAN version

Comment: Linking the associated bug on the issue tracker for posterity: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/5372

Answer (score 5):

The problem was a bug in dev data.table version.
`data.table::update.dev.pkg()` fixed the problem.

Answer (score 3):

It is related to the GForce optimization for `sum` and `mean` which use `gsum` and `gmean`.  It can be either set as FALSE with `options`

```
options(datatable.optimize=1)
```

Or may specifically use `base::mean`, `base::sum`

```
DT[, avg_mean  := base::mean(qty)   , by = .(name, type)]
DT[, avg_sum_N := base::sum(qty)/.N , by = .(name, type)]
```

---

It would be revealed with `verbose`

```
> DT[, avg_mean  := mean(qty)   , by = .(name, type), verbose = TRUE]
Argument 'by' after substitute: .(name, type)
Detected that j uses these columns: [avg_mean, qty]
Finding groups using forderv ... forder.c received 6 rows and 2 columns
0.001s elapsed (0.001s cpu) 
Finding group sizes from the positions (can be avoided to save RAM) ... 0.001s elapsed (0.000s cpu) 
Getting back original order ... forder.c received a vector type 'integer' length 5
0.001s elapsed (0.001s cpu) 
lapply optimization is on, j unchanged as 'mean(qty)'
GForce optimized j to 'gmean(qty)'
Making each group and running j (GForce TRUE) ... gforce initial population of grp took 0.000
gforce assign high and low took 0.000
This gmean took (narm=FALSE) ... gather took ... 0.000s
0.000s
gforce eval took 0.000
0.001s elapsed (0.002s cpu) 
Assigning to 6 row subset of 6 rows
RHS_list_of_columns == false
> DT[, avg_mean  := base::mean(qty)   , by = .(name, type), verbose = TRUE]
Argument 'by' after substitute: .(name, type)
Detected that j uses these columns: [avg_mean, qty]
Finding groups using forderv ... forder.c received 6 rows and 2 columns
0.002s elapsed (0.001s cpu) 
Finding group sizes from the positions (can be avoided to save RAM) ... 0.001s elapsed (0.001s cpu) 
Getting back original order ... forder.c received a vector type 'integer' length 5
0.001s elapsed (0.001s cpu) 
lapply optimization is on, j unchanged as 'base::mean(qty)'
GForce is on, left j unchanged
Old mean optimization is on, left j unchanged.
Making each group and running j (GForce FALSE) ... 
  collecting discontiguous groups took 0.000s for 5 groups
  eval(j) took 0.000s for 5 calls
0.001s elapsed (0.001s cpu)
```

---

If we want to make use of the GForce optimization, then we may need to order with the `by` columns first i.e. can use `setkey`

```
setkey(DT, name, type)
DT[, avg_sum_N := sum(qty)/.N , by = .(name, type)]
DT[, avg_mean  := mean(qty)   , by = .(name, type)]
> DT
Key: <name, type>
     qty   name   type avg_sum_N avg_mean
   <int> <char> <char>     <num>    <num>
1:     4      a      f         4        4
2:     1      a      i         2        2
3:     3      a      i         2        2
4:     6      b      f         6        6
5:     2      b      i         2        2
6:     5      c      f         5        5
```

Comment: Thank you @akrun. But this behavior seems to me (a regular user) a bit inconsistent, I would expect that it works regardless options settings.  How do we know when to adjust proper options to get the code executed the way we expect? Best regards and thanks.

Comment: @FabioCorrea A bug free way would be to create a row index column first,`DT[, rn := .I]` then use `setkey(DT, name, type)` and then your code.  In the end you can reorder with `DT[order(rn)]`

Comment: Since this is related to ordering you could also use `keyby` instead of `by` and achieve the same effect.